# Pod stuck in Pending state after using custom release name in Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Apologize if this comes under basic. I am using stable/rabbitmq community helm chart to install. But whenever I changed release name using --name option in install like `helm install --name rabbitmq stable/rabbitmq`, it gives this error: 0/7 nodes are available: 1 PodToleratesNodeTaints, 7 MatchNodeSelector and hangs indefinitely. And if default/auto generated name is used then it creates release. I don't want to use default release name as it creates unpredictable service name as well. Can someone please help me understanding this? Or is there a way to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You likely have an old release with the same name that hasn't been killed off. Assuming this is a test environment, Try `helm delete rabbitmq --purge` to "flush" your release and then try creating it with `helm install --name rabbitmq stable/rabbitmq` again.

Comment: I tried this. Then after pod stuck in "Pending" state waiting node to be allocated. I think this is something to do with helm charts. When you create charts using `helm create <chart_name>`, it creates roles in labels section which is used to schedule pod on node.

Comment: did you check if you have enough resources to schedule it?
I've strongly used helm, and almost everytime was basically the wrong node.

Comment: I already checked this. There are enough resources available to schedule pod. I tried this with ES as well. Here it is stuck while creating pod: `Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  10s (x21 over 4m)  default-scheduler  0/7 nodes are available: 1 PodToleratesNodeTaints, 4 MatchNodeSelector, 7 NoVolumeZoneConflict.`

Comment: Find the pod's name with `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`, and then describe the pod with `kubectl describe pod <pod_name>`. It may show an error at the bottom of the output. In my case, the error was "persistentvolumeclaim "pgsql-volume-claim" not found".